# Copy and Paste data if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel vba. I need data in B3:D3 to be copied in A6:C6. The code must check for data in A6:C6. If there are existing values then it must be copied to the below cell i.e., A7:C7.

[image]

```
Sub CopyandPaste()

Dim lrow As Integer
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:D3").Copy 'Cell to copy
lrow = 100 'End row
For i = 6 To 100 'Loop from row 6 to 100
If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then 'If cell is empty then paste new value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code you have tried (please include it in your question) and what problems are you having with it?

Comment: Please have a look at [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and please ask a question (you didn't ask one yet). Because this is not a code writing service you cannot expect us to write the code for you if you tell us your requirements. Reading [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: So now that you have posted your attempt, what is the issue with your code? What errors do you get? Where did you get stuck? What does your code do vs. what did you expect it to do?